# Log4j: FileAppender on file relative to classpath

Tags: java, log4j

I managed to properly put a configuration file for log4j and direct to it with this:

```
URL logProperties =  Program.class.getResource("log.properties");
PropertyConfigurator.configure(logProperties.getFile());
```

( I think it can do simpler, I read something about the default properties file, but is not the actual topic) 
Question is: property file is loaded from the class path of the calling method, which is fine, but I have in the config something like:

```
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=console.log
```

I was wondering 'console.log' was in the classpath too, but unfortunately it seems to be in the current directory of the executable ( Launching from eclipse, is in the directory parent of the /bin folder).
Is there some way to specify a file in the classpath, of course without specifying the full path as **log4net** does?
**EDIT**
by this SO question [What is the .NET equivalent of java's System.getProperty("user.dir")?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1827258/566608) I learn the equivalence of `System.getProperty("user.dir")`
and the .NET

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

unfortunately it seems to me that writing ${user.dir}/console.log does not make any differebce ( ie log seems to stay in the current directory, instead of near the executable.

Answer (score 0):

The entry

```
log4j.appender.R.File=console.log
```

defines the output of your logging statements i.e. where the log statements in your code should go.
It makes no sense to put this output file in your classpath. Instead (if no other path is specified) the file is written in the working directory (current directory) of your application.

Comment: there is a big difference between the working directory ant the location where the program lay. I would place it *near* the program, how can I do?

Comment: The easisest solution would be to specify the path, i.e. `log4j.appender.R.File=C:/myapplication/log/console.log`. If you have an installation routine for your software, the installer could write this path to the configuration file.

Comment: this would work, but what if the user move the app somewhere else?

Comment: Then your first comment is no longer viable. If you have an application in a certain directory and the user starts it there, then the log file is put in that directory. If the user starts the application from a different directory by e.g. a shell file the shell file would no longer work when you move the application.

Comment: Let's assume your application folder is `/myapp` and your program is in `/myapp/bin` and started from this directory. The I'd write the logs to `/myapp/logs` by using the relative path `log4j.appender.R.File=../logs/console.log`

Comment: what's appen if some other coder will programmatically change the working directory. Unsafe in my opinion.

Comment: how would you do that in a Java application?